# NSNotification order problem

Tags: iphone, nsnotifications

I am using NSNotification in my app, but it seems that when I send two notifications at very close time interval, the notifications arrive out-of-order -- the one I sent first got received last.

I am wondering if there is a way to ensure that the notifications be processed in the order they are sent.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you post simple notifications (not distributed, not on other threads, etc.), the notification is handled completely synchronously. I.e., after your call to [NSNotificationCenter postNotification...] the notification will have been sent and received by all observers. Out-of-order is impossible in that case.

Comment: There are at least 3 cases: what you call simple, from another thread, and distributed. From the question, and assuming your answer is correct, we can assume it is not case 1, which is the only one you addressed. That makes this answer too incomplete to be useful.

Comment: Possible, I was assuming that someone using the latter cases would know how to serialize concurrent processes. And that the real problem was that the OP was measuring incorrectly.